# What song is this, sung by Sarah Vaughan in the movie "One Special Night?"

Tags: soundtrack

Playing from 1:09:00 to 1:10:45 in [this TV movie](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0165543/) is a brief excerpt of a wonderful piece sung by Sarah Vaughan. Catherine (Julie Andrews) listens to it in her car, after Robert (James Garner) tells her earlier in the movie that Sarah is one of his favorite artists.

Here are the lyrics:

```
Life is just breathing in and out again
Keep it short, keep it simple they say
But hard as I try to keep this ? of you
Oh what I wouldn't give for the chance to see you

Seeing you

Never knew how easily my life would change
After one special moment with you
I could get used to those dinners for two
And mornings that start off with seeing you
```

Google isn't helping much in this case.

In case you have Amazon Prime and would like to listen to it, you may (legally and ethically) record and download the movie as .MP4 using the [PlayOn recording service](https://www.playon.tv/). Here it is on [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07H9KGSPB).

Does anyone know what song this is? Unfortunately the credits don't include the soundtrack performances. I'd like to find the album and purchase a copy if possible.

Comment: **Questions regarding identification of songs/music are off-topic** for Movies & TVas **trivia**. You might try [**MusicFans Exchange**](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/) but check their guidelines before posting. In addition, there are many apps that will enable music identification.

Comment: It's not Sarah Vaughan. Searching for the first two lines of the lyrics should lead you here: https://www.bnd.com/living/liv-columns-blogs/answer-man/article32103618.html

Comment: @Legion600 ~ Oddly, StartPage (I use it instead of Google, for the privacy) didn't find it. SP is supposed to return Google results, but it seems to have gotten its wires crossed this time around.

Comment: @Paulie_D ~ Thanks for the link to Music Fans. Do you happen to have such a link for movie id questions as well?

Comment: There isn't one on Stack Exchange although SF&F will support questions about SF movies...but see https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4129/how-can-i-find-the-title-of-a-movie-from-just-a-description-or-image

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It wasn't Sarah Vaughan.  Though somewhat reminiscent of her song, "Tenderly", it was actually a completely different song.

According to [this article](https://www.bnd.com/living/liv-columns-blogs/answer-man/article32103618.html), it was Carmen Lundy singing a song called "Seeing You".

> “The production company could only afford to license the Sarah Vaughan
>   version of ‘Tenderly’ for the initial two network (showings) of the
>   movie,” he wrote. “I was hired to score the movie, and my wife,
>   Gloria, and I wrote the song ‘Seeing You’ for the ‘foreign’ or
>   international version of the film. We cast a jazz singer by the name
>   of Carmen Lundy to channel Sassy, and she apparently did a helluva
>   job.”
>
> Indeed she did. We’re betting you were fooled by the substitution of
>   Lundy singing “Seeing You” for Vaughan’s “Tenderly” by the time you
>   saw the film. But just so there are no hard feelings, here’s your
>   reward: Bellis was gracious enough to send me an mp3 copy of Lundy’s
>   performance, which I will send on to you. The magic of Hollywood lives
>   on.

This was actually the first Google hit I found when copy/pasting the first 2 lines of lyrics.

Comment: I'm sorry, was this answer wrong or incomplete?

Comment: Some people downvote answers to off-topic questions purely to discourage people from doing it, regardless of the quality of the answer. Of course, that only works if you explain the downvote - which again, some people don't do.

Comment: Goodness, Carmen does a *great* job right there at singing Sarah! Thanks so much for finding that article—I'm now a proud new [Carmen Lundy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JhgQc0wT644) fan :-) Oddly, though, StartPage (I use it instead of Google, for the privacy) didn't find it. SP is supposed to return Google results, but it seems to have gotten its wires crossed this time around. Anyway, thanks again.